# Ruby Split string in parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby1.8.7

I want to split 
"Hello World(...1234)" into two parts 
"Hello World" and "1234"

Thanks in advance for putting your time and effort in providing me correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.......:

```
"Hello World(...1234)".split /\(\.{3}|\)/
```

**will result in** =>  `"Hello World" and "1234"`

=D

Comment: That is oddly specific :)

Comment: Yeap, I know =). Once his real problem isn't clear enough, I didn't try to made a generic solution, but a specific one. Something that does exacly what he asked for. When he give more details about his need, maybe we can do more for him =)

Answer (score 0):

If it's always digits you want to split the string at:

```
@digits = @string.split(/\d/)
```

Done.

Comment: Show how this splits the string according to the OPs need.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Hello World(...1234)".tr(')', '').split('(...')
```

Makes use of `tr()` to replace the closing paren and then splits on the remaining extra characters to give you the parts you want in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
irb(main):001:0> "Hello World(...1234)".split(/\W+/)
```

The result would be:

```
=> ["Hello", "World", "1234"]
```